# SQL Date format in schema definition

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, date-format, date-formatting

For "date1" attribute of my table I am trying to insert date of the format

```
YEAR-MONTH-DAY HOUR:MIN:SEC
```

Do I have ot define this format in the schema?
All I have done is

```
date1 DATE NULL
```

I know I can use DATE_FORMAT(), but I think only for retrieving/querying purposes.
What about recording data in the table?

Comment: How are you trying to write your data?  Do you have an interface that allows you to simply type it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to insert a date with the time you need to instantiate it with datetime

```
date1 DATETIME NULL
```

[SEE DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

alternatively you can store it as a `TIMESTAMP`. both store in that format

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is fine (though you'll need `DATETIME` if wanting to preserve the time component), there aren't formatting options for how a `DATETIME` type is stored.

As long as the data you're inserting has a valid datetime format (the one you posted is fine) then you don't need to do anything else.  Some non-standard formats will require a fix prior to insert.

The `DATE_FORMAT()` function is for displaying a `DATE`/`DATETIME` in a chosen format, but how the data is stored is defined solely by the data type.